# Confused about intensity of a laser beam

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, laser

For normal natural light coming from the sun, the electromagnetic waves emanate from the sun with a spherical wavefront, then we can calculate the intensity of these waves reaching us on Earth by $ I = \frac {P}{4 \pi r^2}$

We used the surface area $ 4 \pi r^2$ because we know the wavefront is spherical, but in the case of lasers, how do we approach this using the idea of wavefronts?

I know it's easy to imagine that a laser beam with a negligible divergence has a specific diameter and we can calculate the intensity by dividing by $ \pi r^2$ because the beam has a circular cross section, but how are we sure that's right? I searched for the type of the laser wavefront and I found that it is called the Gaussian wavefront, is it responsible for this kind of intensity and is it even relevant to what I'm talking about or am I just overthinking?

Comment: Search for the "waist" of a laser beam.

Comment: I would add to @CinaedSimson, search Gaussian beam, Gaussian optics, laser modes.Basically there exist very reliable approximations to what the laser light is, as an analytical expression, when it propagates in free space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We often make the approximation that a laser beam is in the so-called "fundamental Gaussian mode" where the intensity of the laser beam falls off exponentially as we move away from the beam axis in the transverse plane. [1]

The Gaussian beam is the lowest-order solution of the Helmholtz equation in the paraxial approximation. [2]

This is only a simplified picture however: the Gaussian beam does not describe every possible beam, only a subset. Any full solution can be described by the complete Hermite-Gaussian or Laguerre-Gaussian modes. [3]

In general, the intensity is dependent on position in the beam, so it will be a function of position rather than just a number as in your example. Then we integrate it over some area to get the beam power passing through that area.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation#Paraxial_approximation

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam#Hermite-Gaussian_modes